# PayPal iOS Sandbox gives Error 520002, Network Timeout and Session Time Out

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, paypal

I have created a buyer test account in the PayPal sandbox and have used it to attempt to make a purchase via PayPal both in their Simple Demo App and in my own project. Running the app gives back a variety of errors such as `Error ID 520002` or `Network Timeout` or `Session TimeOut`.

It has never successfully run a purchase.

I've read that these errors are due to bugs in the Sandbox. Anybody hear or know anything else?

Also, is there anything that I am possibly doing that is causing these errors? In other words, how do I get this to work!

Answer (score 0):

I have just integrated the simple Demo App in my own app, I run into the same problem: Make sure you added not only the Paypal.h and so but the frameworks too.(there are three to guarantee the connection).

I got rid of the complicated buttons and methods, only stayed with the simple payment function, one button, and the adjustTaxes function. Works fine.

Maybe you are doing something more complicated, if you explained further.

Let me know if you want to take a look at same code.